# Receiving a JSON object from a node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, mongodb

I have a client-side javascript/jquery file that requests a user's info (a JSON object) from a node.js server-side code. The node.js code in turn uses the login credentials supplied by the front end to retrieve the info from a mongodb database. The node.js server is successful in receiving the login credentials and finding the corresponding user in the database, but when it tries to send the JSON object back to the front end, the front end complains of an error:

Also, as additional info, the front end can successfully tell the node server to insert a user into the mongodb database, but when the server tries to send back the message "inserted new user," the front-end doesn't seem to receive anything. This makes me think that the main problem is that something is wrong with the way i'm trying to send anything back to the front end.

relevant client-side code:

```
function requestUser(email, password) {
    var url = "/getUser/" + email + "/" + password;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(json) {
            console.log("success: " + json);
            currentUser = JSON.parse(json)
            localStorage.setItem("currentUser", currentUser);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        },
    });
}

function addUser(fnm, lnm, grd, shl, eml, pwd) {
    var url = "/addUser/" + eml + "/" + pwd + "/"
                            + fnm + "/" + lnm + "/"
                            + shl + "/" + grd + "/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html) {
            console.log("success: " + html);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        },
    });
}
```

node.js server code:

```
var http = require("http"),
    mongojs = require("mongojs"),
    express = require('express'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    fs = require("fs"),
  path = require('path'),
    url = require("url"),
  port = process.env.PORT || 8888;

app = express();
app.use(cors());

var uri = "mongodb://jeshaitan:aliro4greatgood@ds036698.mongolab.com:36698/alirodatabase";
var db = mongojs(uri, ["Papers", "Users"]);

app.get('/getUser/:email/:password', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("received getUser request " + req.params.email)
    var user = db.Users.findOne({
        "email": req.params.email,
        "password": req.params.password
    }, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: 'error retrieving the JSON user' });
            }
            else {
                console.log("user found: " + doc.school)
                res.json(doc);
            }
    });
});

app.get('/addUser/:email/:password/:firstname/:lastname/:school/:grade', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("received addUser request")
    db.Users.insert({email:req.params.email, 
                   password:req.params.password, 
                   firstname:req.params.firstname,
                   lastname:req.params.lastname,
                   school:req.params.school,
                   grade:req.params.grade}, function(err, record) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({error: 'error inserting new user'})
        }
        else {
            db.Users.ensureIndex({'email' : 1}, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
            res.send("inserted new user")
        }
    });
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('CORS-enabled Aliro web server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: What is the error from the front end ?

Comment: Cannot GET /libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js%20line%202%20%3E%20eval

Answer (score 1):

This: `dataType: "jsonp",` should instead be: `dataType: "json",` for the type of response your server is sending.

Comment: thanks, but the front end is still receiving an error `Cannot GET /libs/jquery-1.11.3.min.js%20line%202%20%3E%20eval`

Comment: i tried hosting the jquery files on google, but then it gave me a similar error where google said it didnt have jquery line eval...